# When trying to use CompletableFuture class in java, output not being returned, What did I mess up?

Tags: java

New to java and to CompletableFuture class.  My program runs, but doesn't return anything to the console.  Confident its a variable not being printed or assigned somewhere, but haven't been able to figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;


public class AsyncMain {

    public String contents;

    public void process(String output) throws IOException {

        URL address = new URL("https://api.publicapis.org/random?category=animal");

        InputStreamReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new InputStreamReader(address.openStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(reader);

        //String contents = "";
        String line = "";

        while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null){
            if (line.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            contents += line;
        }

        output = contents;
        System.out.println(output.toString());
    }

    public String address_3(String msg){
        try {
            this.process(msg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(msg);
        return msg;

    }

    public String address_2(String msg){
        try {
            this.process(msg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(msg);
        return msg;
    }

    public String address_1() {
        try {
            this.process(null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        AsyncMain as = new AsyncMain();
        CompletableFuture<String> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();

        cf.supplyAsync(as::address_1)
            .thenApply(as::address_2)
            .thenApply(as::address_3);
    }
}
```

I've tried the function 'process' indepent of the CompletableFuture attempt here. It works and returns a string value from the URL object.  But when trying to integrate with CompletableFuture class to Print out 2 values from the URL object. Nothings is being printed to the console.

Comment: Most likely the application exits before the async code can complete. You're using the common `ForkJoinPool` which uses _daemon_ threads.

Comment: Put another way, you are running something asynchronously. That means, essentially, that the task runs in the background and `main` continues running normally. And, of course, once you reach the end of `main`, the program exits whether the asynchronous task is completed or not. You may want to look at `join` or `isDone` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Answer (score 0):

This lines of the code returns a `CompletableFuture`.

```
CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture =
        cf.supplyAsync(as::address_1).thenApply(as::address_2).thenApply(as::address_3);
```

In your case, main thread exist before completion of the `CompletableFuture`. You can see a result if you block the main thread with a sleep.

```
cf.supplyAsync(as::address_1).thenApply(as::address_2).thenApply(as::address_3);
Thread.sleep(5000);
```

`CompletableFuture` defines the contract for asynchronous computation steps that can be combined with other steps.
You can also get the result of `CompletableFuture<String>` by `CompletableFuture.get()` method call, which will also block the main thread until the Future steps are completed.

```
CompletableFuture<String> completableFuture =
        cf.supplyAsync(as::address_1).thenApply(as::address_2).thenApply(as::address_3);
completableFuture.get();
```